Spring Boot @Value not fetching values
The @Value annotation is not fetching data from application.properties
Please check the code in the below repository
https://github.com/dev1ad/props
The @Value in WebController works whereas the @Value in ManualClass does not work!! Not sure why it is not working.

Please take the [tour], read [ask], and then [edit] your question to provide a [mre] as text (not as external link, not as screenshot).

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

You are manually instantiating the ManualClass in your WebController line 17, you need to have the ManualClass be injected by spring and it should have the property value filled in automatically.

thanks for the quick response. appreciate it.

updated the same repo with the corrected code for any reference.
